# SSH stays on port 22 even after editing sshd_config

Tags: ssh, systemd

I tried changing my SSH port from 22 to 220 but it stays on 22.
I used `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to change the daemon config and uncommented the line with Port 22 and changed it.

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

# Port and ListenAddress options are not used when sshd is socket-activated,
# which is now the default in Ubuntu.  See sshd_config(5) and
# /usr/share/doc/openssh-server/README.Debian.gz for details.
Port 220
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

I restarted the ssh service with `sudo service ssh restart`
I also tried `sudo systemctl restart ssh`
I also tried `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
Made sure ssh is enabled with `sudo systemctl enable ssh`
I did several `sudo apt update` and reinstalled openssh-server.
I checked for syntax errors with `sudo sshd -t`

I have ufw disabled.

Wenn I `sudo systemctl status ssh` it outputs:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d
             └─00-socket.conf
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-10 10:51:20 CEST; 19min ago
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 9804 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9805 (sshd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1959)
     Memory: 5.5M
        CPU: 462ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─5792 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
             └─9805 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Oct 10 10:51:20 homePi systemd[1]: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 10 10:51:20 homePi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Found left-over process 5792 (sshd) in con>
Oct 10 10:51:20 homePi systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previou>
Oct 10 10:51:20 homePi sshd[9805]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 10 10:51:20 homePi systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 10 10:51:59 homePi sshd[9870]: Accepted password for xxx from 192.168.178.56 port 4184>
lines 1-23
```

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: yes I have several times. One time I even locked myself out because neither 22 nor 220 worked to ssh in. That was when I had ufw active and enabled port 220 on it

Comment: Seriously?  Are you running Debian on your RPi? And you didn't put that in the **Tags**? FWIW, everyone here will assume you're using RPiOS unless you make that clear with a **Tag** - or state it outright in your question.

Comment: @KeenGently Thats strange, because the error "ssh.service: Found left-over process 5792 (sshd) in co" is indicating that ssh isn't cleanly restarted, and normaly a reboot cleans that up. But your output from the terminal is trunkated, please correct that.

Comment: Notice the `status` makes it pretty clear that it is in fact being *triggered by* `ssh.socket`, ie. is "socket-activated" as per the comment in your `sshd_config` above the `Port` field.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't mention the OS, I'm guessing it's Ubuntu because of this comment in `sshd_config`:

> Port and ListenAddress options are not used when sshd is socket-activated,
> which is now the default in Ubuntu.  See sshd_config(5) and
> /usr/share/doc/openssh-server/README.Debian.gz for details.

This is immediately above your `Port` entry. >_<

That comment isn't in the version on RpiOS, but it still may be using the socket activation.  To check:

```
> systemctl status ssh.socket
● ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
     Listen: [::]:22 (Stream)
```

Notice it says "vendor preset: enabled".  I'm not sure if that is true, since I have no memory of disabling this, nor can I find a trace of it in the scripts I use to bootstrap a new system.  I am **not** using port 22, so  this definitely not being used.

If it is, you could disable this, but there is a simpler suggestion in `/usr/share/doc/openssh-server/README.Debian.gz` under the heading *Per-connection sshd instances with systemd* (there's an explanation of what "socket-activated" means there too):

> The provided ssh.socket unit file sets ListenStream=22.  If you need to have
> it listen on a different address or port, then you will need to do this as
> follows (modifying ListenStream to match your requirements):

I'll restate the instructions that follow because the original might be a bit cryptic.  You need to create a file `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/listen.conf`; you may need to create the `ssh.socket.d` directory first.  All this should be owned root, and in the file:

```
   [Socket]                                                                                                                                                                     
   ListenStream=220
```

Or whatever port number you want. To enable this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart ssh.socket
```

Or just reboot.

Comment: :)  good catch on the Ubuntu thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing wrong, but this works for me:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config 

# FROM: #Port 22    TO: Port 220

$ sudo systemctl reload-or-restart ssh.service 
$ systemctl status sshd.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-10 00:13:56 UTC; 1 day 18h ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 474 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 5402 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 5403 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 521 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1599)
        CPU: 699ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─521 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Oct 11 18:33:16 raspberrypi4b systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 11 18:33:16 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Oct 11 18:33:16 raspberrypi4b systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 11 18:33:16 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 11 18:33:16 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 11 18:58:24 raspberrypi4b systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 11 18:58:24 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Oct 11 18:58:24 raspberrypi4b systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Oct 11 18:58:24 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 220.
Oct 11 18:58:24 raspberrypi4b sshd[521]: Server listening on :: port 220.
```

Note that I used the `reload-or-restart` option w/ `systemctl` because I did not know with certainty that the service (`sshd`) has the functionality to reload its configuration.

To test, I did `logout`, and then reconnect:

```
$ logout
Connection to raspberrypi4b closed. 

seamus@Fumier-Pro ~ % ssh pi@raspberrypi4b
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi4b port 22: Connection refused 

seamus@Fumier-Pro ~ % ssh -p 220 pi@raspberrypi4b
...
Last login: Tue Oct 10 00:14:28 2023 from 192.168.1.209
pi@raspberrypi4b:~ $
```

IOW, this seems to work perfectly on my system, and does exactly what was expected. Why yours doesn't is a mystery to me???

---

###### EDIT:

After reading [@Goldilocks (correct) answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/144630/83790), and realizing I *missed the clue* that indicated you were probably using Ubuntu on your RPi:

My RPi runs RPiOS (bullseye); this shows that **"socket-based activation"** is `inactive`:

```
$ systemctl status ssh.socket 
● ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
     Listen: [::]:22 (Stream)
   Accepted: 0; Connected: 0;
```

OTOH, Ubuntu now uses **"socket-based activation"** by default to start `sshd`; this means the daemon is not started until someone tries to connect to the `sshd` server. This is done to [*"mak[e] Ubuntu as efficient as possible ..."*](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sshd-now-uses-socket-based-activation-ubuntu-22-10-and-later/30189).

See also: [1](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=237077)

###### ALTERNATIVE:

In addition to @Goldilocks (correct) answer, you can ***do this on your Ubuntu installation***:

Disable Ubuntu's (now default) **"socket-based activation"**, and replace it with the *more conventional/straightforward* ***non***-socket-based activation as follows:

```
systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/00-socket.conf
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable --now ssh.service
```

With the above changes, `sshd` configuration on your Ubuntu system will now operate same as with RPiOS.